# Union help on DB2

Tags: sql, db2, union

I am trying to union two queries to show the top 5 customer codes but I keep receiving an error, `SQLSTATE 42601`.
Ideally I would like the query to show something like this.

```
LTIHONIA CLIENT 1 1330
LITHOINA CLIENT 2 1300
LITHONIA CLIENT 3 1000
ATHENS CLIENT 1 1330
ATHENS CLIENT 2 1000
ATHENS CLIENT 3 400
```

---

```
SELECT 'LITHONIA' AS TYPE,  CLIENT_ID, ROUND(DEC(SUM(ORIG_AMT)),2) AS REVENUE FROM AR_SUM AR, TLORDER WHERE AGING_DATE >= '1/1/2016' AND AR.BILL_NUMBER = TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER 
AND CURRENT_STATUS IN ('BILLD','EDIBILLED') AND ORIG_AMT > 0 AND AR.SITE_ID = 'SITE1' 
GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
ORDER BY REVENUE DESC 
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
UNION 
SELECT 'LITHONIA' AS TYPE,  CLIENT_ID, ROUND(DEC(SUM(ORIG_AMT)),2) AS REVENUE FROM AR_SUM AR, TLORDER WHERE AGING_DATE >= '1/1/2016' AND AR.BILL_NUMBER = TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER 
AND CURRENT_STATUS IN ('BILLD','EDIBILLED') AND ORIG_AMT > 0 AND AR.SITE_ID = 'SITE10' 
GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
ORDER BY REVENUE DESC 
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: I think type is reserved word change to ftype.

Answer (score 0):

Try using parentheses around the subqueries:

```
(SELECT 'LITHONIA' AS TYPE,  CLIENT_ID, ROUND(DEC(SUM(ORIG_AMT)),2) AS REVENUE
 FROM AR_SUM AR JOIN
      TLORDER
      ON  AR.BILL_NUMBER = TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER
 WHERE AGING_DATE >= '1/1/2016' AND CURRENT_STATUS IN ('BILLD','EDIBILLED') AND ORIG_AMT > 0 AND AR.SITE_ID = 'SITE1' 
 GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
 ORDER BY REVENUE DESC 
 FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
) UNION 
(SELECT 'LITHONIA' AS TYPE,  CLIENT_ID, ROUND(DEC(SUM(ORIG_AMT)),2) AS REVENUE  
 FROM AR_SUM AR JOIN
      TLORDER
      ON AR.BILL_NUMBER = TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER 
 WHERE AGING_DATE >= '1/1/2016' AND 
       CURRENT_STATUS IN ('BILLD','EDIBILLED') AND ORIG_AMT > 0 AND AR.SITE_ID = 'SITE10' 
 GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
 ORDER BY REVENUE DESC 
 FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
)
```

Also, you should learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  And, `UNION ALL` is probably more appropriate than `UNION`, unless you intend for duplicates to be removed.

Comment: @OVO . . . That is probably a permissions issue on the schema/tables.

Answer (score 0):

@OVO

I am sure that your query has error 42601 due to order by clause. You cant have it in union query.
Remove order by clause from both sqls & put then like select fields from (YOUR UNION SQL) order by bla bla.